# Sourcetree GUI : Why main branch is behind another branch? Is it normal?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I have main branch and ChangeWS branch.
ChangeWS branch is separate from main branch and updated sourcecode.
Sourcecode in ChangeWS branch is updated more than main branch.

[image: Grainy picture of branches]

From picture: main branch is behind ChangeWS branch.

- Is it normal?
- Why main branch is not in main blue line? Why it is red line separate from main blue line.
- Can I merge ChangeWS into main branch? because finally I will merge ChangeWS branch into main branch.

Comment: The picture indicates that you have two commits with "change health", one in each branch. Without information about the contents of these two commits, we can't really say anything more. On the face of it, no, they seem to conflict, although it is possible that the conflicts can be easily reconciled if the contents of the two identically described commits are also basically identical.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure that OP could have asked parts of the question without the screenshot. We may know that this question could be asked by using `git log --graph` from the command line, and then pasting the output, however, I suspect had OP known about that they would have realized that the colors do not matter and have no meaning other than to visually separate paths of commits.

Answer (score 2):

It is totally normal. What you see is a graph representing the current state of branches. It might show it differently if your current branch is main or ChangeWS.

Also, depending on what UI tool you are using the graph could be slightly different. Some tools try to have the main branch in a straight line, but it is not always the case. Again, colours are picked at random to differentiate related parts of the graph.

You can always try to merge and there might be conflicts and you will deal with them if there is one.

A good practice is to pull the latest main branch into your current branch and deal with any conflicts on your branch and then try to merge into main by creating a pull request to the main branch.

This pull request is then passed on to a peer to review and approve the changes which then might result in a merge if you are using something like Bitbucket or Gitlab.